# "The heart can choke the mind when all its blood flows back unto itself."

Tags: meaning-in-context

This quote is Francis Underwood's, from House of Cards, Season 2, Episode 11. Would someone please explain it? Some context can be found [here](http://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2014/02/-em-house-of-cards-em-season-2-the-live-binge-review-episodes-1-to-13/283851/).

I'd venture that it refers to love? It induces the blood to flow back onto the heart? Then no blood circulates to the brain and thus chokes it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be litcrit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to love and how it can "blind" the mind if and when it decides to do so.